# How to wrap italic text in Word within <em> tags?

Tags: regex, ms-word

I need to replace all italicized text in a Word document with that same text wrapped in `<em>` tags, such as:

Original: The *fox* jumped *over the dog*. 
Replaced: The `<em>`*fox*`</em>` jumped `<em>`*over the dog*`</em>`.

I can see how to search for the italicized text, but how can I specify the original found text in the Replace: dialog? Word supports regex, so I was trying something along these lines:

Find: `(*)` (w/ italic Font turned on)
Replace: `<em>\1</em>`

But instead of wrapping any italic string in em tags, it wraps every single character that is italic in an  tag.

Thanks for any help. Note: yes, I could probably do this in another editor more easily; however, for a variety of reasons I need to leave it in Word.

Comment: Why would you do that? It sounds like you would like to convert from Word format to HTML format, but there are surely better ways of doing that.

Comment: trust me, I want to do that.

Comment: More or less, you can’t I’m afraid, since Word does not support “greedy match”.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here is the thing:

- Go to Find -> Advanced Find and Replace -> Replace in Word
- At the very bottom you can choose formatting so choose *Font - Italic*.
- In Replace With choose Special - Find What Text - it will add `^&`.
- Add whatever you want to - example : `<em>^$</em>`